# Spring ldap compounded search requests

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I am new to Spring LDAP and would like to know the following. Is it possible to "compound" 2 or more searches in a single one, while at the same time using an iterator?

For example, my code right now looks something like this:

```
    List result = ldapTemplate.search(baseDn, encode, searchControls2,
            genericContextMapper);
```

BaseDn points to a certain branch of the LDAP tree, and genericContextMapper has an iterator that I am using throught my code to gradually fetch the results.

But what if I want to pass more than 1 BaseDN, each pointing to completely different LDAP branches, and I expect the iterator to start with the next BaseDN as soon as it is done with the previous one? Can I do this kind of chaining through Spring LDAP?

I know I can achieve this by creating my own custom class that just "sticks together" the results, but I was wondering if there is an easier out of the box solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<bean id="authenticator" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.authenticator.BindAuthenticator">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
</bean> 

<bean id="userSearch" class="com.security.OUUserSearch">
    <property name="userSearches" ref="userSearches" />
</bean>

<util:list id="userSearches">
    <ref bean="userSearch1" />
    <ref bean="userSearch2" />
</util:list>

<bean id="userSearch1" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg value="OU=test1" />
    <constructor-arg value="(uid={0})" />
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />

</bean>
<bean id="userSearch2" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg value="OU=test2" />
    <constructor-arg value="(uid={0})" />
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
```

And OUUserSearch is

```
public class OUUserSearch implements LdapUserSearch   
{
List<LdapUserSearch> myUserSearches = null;

public DirContextOperations searchForUser(String theUsername)
{
    DirContextOperations theResult = null;  
    for(LdapUserSearch aSearch : myUserSearches)
    {
        try
        {
            theResult = aSearch.searchForUser(theUsername);
            if (theResult != null)
            {
                // we are done
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String aMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            task.debug(aMessage);
        }
    }
    if (theResult == null)
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unable to authenticate user (" + theUsername + ")");
    }
    return theResult;
}

public List<LdapUserSearch> getUserSearches() { return myUserSearches;}
public void setUserSearches(List<LdapUserSearch> theSearches) {myUserSearches = theSearches;}
```